# database tables for items and their production for a city building game in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Iam working on building a database for a city building game ,something similar to simcity . all is going just fine except fot the tables related to items and the production process .

now items are produced in factories and each factory has a number of production units starting with lets say 2 or 3 and could be increased when factories are upgraded ... each production unit should have one of three states (1-available 2-pending 3-busy ) . what i want to make is a table saving the state of these production units with the products /items being produced . iam not saving the metadata of these factories in the databas.

what i have in mind is a  productionunit_user table ( not factory-user)with columns :UserID,pu_id,PU-status,p_starttime,......
 but eventually this would grow huge as each user may have up to 200 production units .

my question is : what is the best way to represent this items production data in the database .

Comment: If you mean to say the table would have 200 rows, that is NOT a lot.

Comment: 200 rows would be just for one user representing his production units , ... number of users my grow rapidly .

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to be specific about this - but as long as you're accessing this table by an indexed column, your design will easily scale to hundreds of thousands or millions of users.

I'm guessing your most common query would be something like:

```
select *
from productionunit_user
where UserID = ?
```

As long as you have an index on UserID, that should be super quick with HUGE numbers of rows (tens or hundreds of millions) on a decently sized server.

However, if you anticipate queries that can't use indexes - string comparison, complex arithmetic on dates or quantities - you *may* have a scalability problem.

Comment: well thanks for your ans , and yes  most queries would be as you mentioned , but is that the right way adding these data to a table , where you have factories and in each factory you have a number of production units , im just thinking is there might be other way ??